# What are normal values for EMG/nerve conduction studies?

Tags: neurology, measurement, nerves

Where can I find a detailed table of normal values for NCS (nerve conduction studies) for the various arm nerves - ulnar, median, radial; including both motor and sensory component of each nerve; latency, amplitude, and conduction velocity; and various points of measurement on each nerve (above elbow, below elbow, wrist, etc....)?

Answer (score 2):

[This paper](https://www.aanem.org/getmedia/c58afeb5-4164-47f2-b7a4-519ff08a26e6/Chen_et_al-2016-Muscle_-_Nerve.pdf) might be of interest to you (1)
They have attempted to summarize together a table of the values for the common upper and lower limb nerves including both sensory and motor.
It is quite detailed in the location of the electrodes, and includes latency, amplitude and conduction velocity which you are looking for.

Paper:
(1) Chen, S.; Andary, M.; Buschbacher, R.; Del Toro, D.; et al. Electrodiagnostic reference values for upper and lower limb nerve conduction studies in adult populations. *Muscle & Nerve.* 2016 Sept;54(3):371-7